# "Hat trading company" vs "Hat-trading company"

Tags: hyphenation

> Last year I worked for X, a hat-trading company

or

> Last year I worked for X, a hat trading company

For some reason I was inclined to go with the hyphenated version, which now seems wrong, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Either one is fine, but I would go with the hyphen to link *hat* and *trading* together as a modifier of company. In your case, though, *hat trading company* makes perfect sense, as  you are talking about a trading company that specializes in hats. The choice may depend on the context, e.g., on whether you are emphasizing *company* as part of a comparison of one type of company to another.

Answer (score 0):

> Either one is fine, but I would go with the hyphen to link hat and trading together as a modifier of company. In your case, though, hat trading company makes perfect sense, as you are talking about a trading company that specializes in hats. The choice may depend on the context, e.g., on whether you are emphasizing company as part of a comparison of one type of company to another. – Richard Kayser

Comment: I would interpret a hat-trading company as a company that makes money trading hats , and a hat trading company as trading company that, among other items, trades hats.. Here is a clearer example. The nuclear power plant ordered five hundred-foot long rods, but it was sent five-hundred foot long rods.